# Angular Material Dialog dialogref.close() not working

Tags: angular, typescript

the close isnt working, the dialogRef.close() is undefined??

Here is the code
template

```
   <button  mat-raised-button (click)="openModal()">Open Project Specifics</button>
```

TS

```
  openModal(){
   let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ProjectSpecificContentComponent, {
   data:{projectsSpecifics: this.projectSpecific},
      panelClass: 'project-content-dialog'
 })
     dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => console.log(result))
  }
```

here is the called Component

```
    <button mat-dialog-close>X</button>

              <div class="container">
                <div class="project-specific" *ngFor="let projectS of projectSpecificList">
               <h5>{{projectS.name}}</h5>
                <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="mat-group">
                 <mat-label>Add project specific</mat-label>
          <mat-select multiple>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let item of getContent(projectS)">{{item.content}}</mat- 
            option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
         </div>

       </div>
       <div mat-dialog-actions>
         <button (click)="onClose()" mat-raised-button>Done!</button>
       </div>
```

and TS

```
           constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
             public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ProjectSpecificContentComponent>,
                 ) { }



                      onClose(){
                        this.dialogRef.close();
                        }
```

Also here you can see the module where i imported the component

```
   imports[MatDialogModule]
   entryComponents: [ProjectSpecificContentComponent]
```

Comment: please share a stackblitz with the issue

Answer (score 0):

My dialog code(TS) is like this:

```
export class DialogFormComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    public matDialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogFormComponent>, 
  )

  onClose(){
    this.matDialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

You can try the same way

Comment: the problem is the close method, i cant close the dialog

Comment: I'm so sorry I misread the question，I have revised the answer

Answer (score -1):

Step 1:

```
public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<any>,
```

add this in your constructor

Step 2:
after defining material dialog, assign your local variable dialogRef to global this.dialogRef variable

**this.dialogRef = dialogRef;**

step 3: now execute **this.dialogRef.close()**

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: If you have step one in constructor, where the local variable comes from?
Did you read the code provided?